# Can I convert a 2D video to 3D?

Tags: wine, 3d, conversion

Is it possible to convert a 2D video to 3D on Linux?

There are several ways on Windows, one is using an [AviSynth script](http://3dvision-blog.com/1248-converting-2d-videos-to-3d-using-virtualdub-and-the-avisynth-script/).
I tried opening the script with avconv.exe and VirtualDub with Wine and AviSynth, but it fails to load AviSynth.dll.

Comment: I think that youtube is capable of converting your video from 2d to 3d! But I don't know much about it.

Comment: It is, but I'm always working offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed AviSynth with Wine 1.3.16 through PlayOnLinux, then I chose "System" version. I replaced `DirectShowSource` with `AviSource` in the script and I could open the script with VirtualDub.

Answer (score -1):

One software that can help you is [Bino](http://bino3d.org/index.html). But, it is just a 3D video player, not a stuff to convert and save them into 3D. I think, recording screen may help if you want to save them into 3D.

Comment: Bino can only play 3D videos, it cannot convert and play 2D videos into 3D.